# submit a form that is on the same page without refeshing the page

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery

so here it is a confusing battle. i want to submit a form that is on the same page
as my php validation.

html

```
 <form id="form">
  //fields
  <input type="submit" id="submit">
  </form>

<?php
/ /check if form is good
?>
```

jquery

```
$("#actvpost").submit(function(){
    //code
  return false;
});
```

when i hit submit the page still refreshes how can i have it to just send the data without
using an external page

i can do it without jquery but it will refresh the page, i would like to attach jquery to so that it does not refresh the page.

Comment: you might want to use JavaScript validation

Comment: have you added jquery library properly

Comment: ^ Chrome web inspector > firebug * 1000

Answer (score 5):

The id of your form should be `actvpost` not `form`, as you are referencing `actvpost` in your jQuery selector.

Your submit function should not `return false`, but should instead make use of `event.preventDefault`:

```
$("#actvpost").submit(function( event ){
    event.preventDefault();
    // your code
});
```

**The `event` object**

All events are passed an `event` object as their first argument, on trigger. This object contains many useful properties about the event, such as `event.target` and `event.type` (which returns click, keyup, ect...). jQuery also extends this object with useful methods such as `preventDefault()`

Although it is not necessary, I do recommend putting the `event.preventDefault()` early, if not first in your handler. This, again, not imperative, but a good practice if you plan on writing more complex code in the future. Organization is key, everything should follow some sort of common convention. It is much easier to solve problems when you code with *any* convention, let alone a common convention.

Essentially, you cannot run PHP without a new HTTP request, so alternatively, you may want to use solely javascript validation *before* submit, with server side validation as a last line of defense. To submit the form to your PHP script, you would want either:

- Use AJAX (jQuery makes this simple)
- Submit to an iframe, while listening on its "load" event for a response in Javascript

Both of which make a new HTTP request and make the response available in javascript.

Comment: _"Notice that preventDefault is called before further execution of your script, this is important."_ - You seem to be saying that `event.preventDefault()` must be the first line of the submit event handler? That is definitely _not_ true, you just have to put it somewhere before returning from the event handling function - the submit will _not_ continue until that function completes. Also, `return false` will prevent the default, so your advice not to use `return false` is unfounded. _"You cannot run PHP without a full page refresh"_ - Yes you can: make an Ajax request to a PHP page...

Comment: It is not imperative that it is the first line, but it is good practice. When working with asynchronous methods as much as I do, it _is_ imperative. My comment on PHP may be misleading, but it was meant to address the code that the OP had at the time - it appeared that he was trying to run php directly from javascript, which is not possible. The answer has been rephrased.

Comment: Cool. I agree with the practice of putting `event.preventDefault()` on the first line when the particular event handler involved _always_ prevents the default behaviour. For a more complicated handler that only prevents the default sometimes obviously you'd need `event.preventDefault()` inside some sort of conditionals - though in such situations it can be easier to return false from that point...

Comment: It was a good point that you corrected me on, I ended up researching it and admit I was wrong. Thanks for the correction, my answer has been changed to reflect it.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe:

```
$("#actvpost").submit(function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  // here you may by your self send request and get response
});
```

And maybe you would use something like jQuery Form Plugin and use `ajaxForm` function.

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
<form id="form">
```

With:

```
<form id="actvpost">
```